# Android GCM messaging sending data from the service to activity

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Generally speaking.

I have an app that can receive data from Google APP Engine via Google Cloud MEssaging (GCM).

In one instance an Activity-X will call a http-get towards the GCM server which will trigger a GCM message back to the APP.  The APP has a Service extended from GCMBaseIntentService to register and receive GCM messages.  So that part works, Activity-X does  and this triggers a GCM message from server to APP.  The APP's GCMBaseIntentService gets triggered and receives the data.

how do i get the received data back to the activity which called the ?

Answer (score 1):

Create an `Intent` which your custom action, fill its extras with the data, and send it to the `Activity`.

Comment: But the activity is already started ... what do you mean "sendit"

Comment: @user1840829: That depends on your particular use case, whether or not you would like the `Intent` to start the `Activity` were it not running. Otherwise, just send the intent to the `Activity` as a _broadcast_.